# React Class to manage imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How could I make a react class that manages all my import paths?
like

```
import Paths from './Paths'
import LoginScreen from Paths.LoginScreen
```

Because Visual Studio Code has no refactoring feature.

package.json

```
{
    "name": "githubrepo",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.16.2",
        "native-base": "^2.3.2",
        "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
        "react-native": "0.48.3",
        "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "21.0.2",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
        "jest": "21.1.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using webpack? It does it for you.

Comment: I use react native and not sure if it has webPack but there is package.json

Comment: Package.json is independent of webpack but it might contain scripts to run the application. Can you send me your package.json

Comment: @AbhinavJain I added it in the question

Comment: You are not using webpack. Any reason for that?
It is highly recommended to use webpack.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an export keyword, e.g:

```
export class LoginScreen..... etc
```

Imports can be managed by doing:

```
import { LoginScreen } from Paths
```

Comment: I know export but what if I made several exports is it will affect the performance?

Comment: export Login and export Register is all classes will be loaded if I import the Paths class